# Retrieve an entity without its relationships using JPA without Lazy Loading

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have an entity which has `OneToMany` relationships with other entities such as the `Boat` entity below. In reality, the entity has *many* fields.

```
@Entity
public class Boat {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Gun> guns;

    public List<Gun> getGuns() {
        return guns;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

For some searches, I am only interested in the Basic attributes of `Boat` and do not want to retrieve any `OneToMany` relationships. One option is to make all `OneToMany` relationships with `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`.

However, lazy loading creates two issues:

1. Lazy loading creates a proxy around the `OneToMany` relationship which I do not need. I do not need to access the `OneToMany` relationship **at all** and I need every performance improvement I can get.
2. Many other queries require eager fetching, and changing all `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` relationships to lazy fetching would make other queries cumbersome.

Is there a way to choose which relationships should be retrieved dynamically without using lazy fetching. Is this possible using standard JPQL?

I am using EclipseLink in Glassfish.

I have previously investigate EclipseLink fetch groups, which sort of tackles my issue. However, I ran in to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577864/classdescriptor-returns-null-fetchgroupmanager-when-trying-to-create-an-eclipsel

Comment: As far as I am concirn, lazy loading is the default one, and if you are using ORM framework you cannot have entity materialized without proxy. Thats the whole point to have proxy for such tasks like lazy loading or updating only "if needed". I really don't think that entity proxies are going to be your performance bottleneck.

Comment: In many queries I don't want to resolve the relationships, so nothing will be materializing without the proxy. Even if there is no performance issue with indirection, setting all relationships to `lazy` will detriment all my other queries which need eager loading. In addition, EclipseLink does not support `lazy` as a fetch mode for one-to-one and many-to-one relationships in Java SE [`lazy` will be ignored]. So using lazy on these relationships will only work in a Java EE container.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return a boat entity if all you want is the name or other basic attributes.  JPA allows returning raw data rather than your manged entities if tht is what you are after.  Using lazy on a relationship that isn't always required though will speed things up, not slow it down, but it does require planning when serialization might be involved and the relation is needed.  Eclipselink also provides fetch and attribute groups to partially load entities as needed.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup for details

Comment: In reality, my entity is very large and it would be a cumbersome workaround to retrieve the data like so.

Comment: Telling JPA what you want isn't a workaround.  Did you look at attribute groups as that might be more along what you want.